# How to stop google MapsActivity from rerouting my route?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

startActivity(intent);
```

for providing navigation support in my app , but whenever I go off route than it draws a new route to the destination. How to stop it, I want the route to be fixed